# Select2 Not working with bootstrap Modal window

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, bootstrap-modal

I am unable to type in the select2 dropdown when in modal. I know there were similar questions asked before. I have tried everything suggested in the forums. Here are the parts of code related to my modal window using select2.

Index.cshtml:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" id="TicketCircuit" role="button">CABS</a>


<div id="TicketCABSModal"></div>


     $("#TicketCircuit").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CABS", "Maintenanace")',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#TicketCABSModal').html(data);
        $('#TicketCABS').modal('show');
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, status, error) {
        alert('failed: ' + error + ' status ' + status);
    });
});
```

I am calling the MVC controller to get the View html data.Below is the View.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="TicketCABS"  role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" style="">
        <div class="modal-header ">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">CABS</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" >

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default ">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following suggestions:

1. Remove **tabindex**
2. Alter the **Z-index**
3. Override`$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus` in the following ways `$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus=function(){};`

   and

   `$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
       var that = this;
       $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
           if ($(e.target).hasClass('select2-modal')) {
               return true;
           }
           if (that.$element[0] !== e.target && !that.$element.has(e.target).length) {
               that.$element.focus();
           }
       });
   };`

None of the above solutions worked. I am using **Bootstrap V3.3.4** ,**Jquery 2.1.4** and **select2 V 3.5.2** . I am not sure why it is not working. Please help!!

Comment: Please create Fiddle. I'd fixed this issue in past but unfortunately, I don't remember. I can fix it again if you provide the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a simple fix to my problem. Hope it will be useful for someone. I just used **$(selector).append(data)** instead of **$(selector).html(data)**. It was pretty simple at the end.